# Python single dispatch functions (PEP 443)

Tags: python

I have a piece of code looking like that:

```
funcs = {'one': self.one,
         'two': self.two,
        }

def dispatch(var):
    funcs[var]()
```

But for a lot more than just two functions -- a couple of dozen are needed in the end.  I had a look at [PEP 443 - Single-dispatch generic](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0443/) and I think it might help.  However, I am not sure if this is:

1. A good idea -- pythonic?
2. How to do it?

**Edit**: More information as to what I do...  I am getting commands (strings) that I need to parse.  Depending on which command is received, a different parser is called. The first word of the command is always unique and predefined, the rest is dependent on said first word.  I *could* create a whole grammar and do it that way but this is overkill.  Examples of a command would be:

```
servo 0 start_move
head 5 0xff 0xab 0x34
...
```

Comment: Shouldn't `funcs['var']()` be `funcs[var]()`?

Comment: That PEP is proposing something completely different. Your function is perfectly fine (after you change `'var'` to `var`). Why do you need two dozen of these functions? What are you making?

Comment: Can you give us more context.

Comment: First of all, it's probably something like `funcs[var]()`, otherwise it won't work

Comment: Without seeing more of your code, it's hard to tell if PEP 443 applies to you. What do those two functions `self.one` and `self.two` do? How exactly is `dispatch` called in your code? The PEP you linked proposes a way of using a single *generic* function on multiple types, without having to explicitly check the type of the argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PEP 443 is proposing a method to do what is essentially [function overloading](http://lukasz.langa.pl/8/single-dispatch-generic-functions/) in Python. In any case, since it appears to be slated to be included in Python 3.4, using it could cause compatibility issues if people with other versions of Python try using your code.

I think your original version is fine. As the comments note, you need to turn `var` from a string into a variable (typo?) but apart from that, your method should easily scale up.

However, since manually keeping track of all the different functions and their names may get tiresome after a point, you could perhaps experiment with creating a decorator to automatically record and keep track of the function names and construct the function dict:

```
class Functions(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.funcs = {}

    def add(self, func):
        self.funcs[func.__name__] = func
        return func

    def dispatch(self, name, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.funcs[name](*args, **kwargs)

a = Functions()

@a.add
def test(foo):
    return foo + 3

@a.add
def hello(bar):
    return bar * 3

print a.dispatch('test', 6)    # returns 9
print a.dispatch('hello', 6)   # returns 18
```

Comment: +1 I'd like to point out that this can return unexpected results when you have multiple decorators attached to a function. `@a.add` should (probably) always be the top decorator and the inner function for subsequent functions should have it's `__name__` changed to the passed function's `__name__`. E.G. `def dec(func): #define inner# inner.__name__ = func.__name__ ; return inner`

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for something like:

```
class A(object):
    def a(self):
        print 'aaa'

    def b(self):
        print 'bbb'
a = A()
getattr(a, 'a')()  # output: aaa
getattr(a, 'b')()  # output: bbb
```