# How do i write a function acting on a list properly?

Tags: python, list

In Python, I would like to have a function working on different input types. Something like this:

```
def my_square(x):
    return x ** 2

my_square(2)             #return 4
my_square(range(10))     #should return a list [0 ... 81]

npa = numpy.zeros(10)
my_square(npa)           # should return a numpy array with the squares of zeros
```

Basically, what is good practice to write functions for both scalars and iterables? Can this be done with *args or *kwargs perhaps?

Comment: Why not write the function to work only on scalars then e.g. `map` it onto iterables? You certainly *can* handle both within the function, but I'd try to avoid it.

Comment: It's a bad idea to do what you're trying to do, except in fringe cases. Write versions for each type of input.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Numpy arrays are designed so that expressions can be written that work whether the variables used within are scalars or arrays. The OP's `my_square(x)` will work equally as well whether `x = 4` or `x` is an `ndarray` of one million entries. In this case, writing a function that accepts either a scalar or an iterable is a common numerical python idiom used in many scientific packages, and using `map` to apply it to an iterable is decidedly an anti-pattern. But if the function is general (and can't take advantage of numpy's vectorization), then a list comp. or map is the way to go.

Comment: @jme interesting, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A typical way to do this is to use `numpy.asarray` to convert the input of your function to an `ndarray`. If the input is a scalar, then the result is an array with 0 dimensions, which acts essentially like a Python number type. For instance:

```
def square(x):
    x = np.asarray(x)
    return x**2
```

So that:

```
>>> square(4)
16
>>> square([1, 2, 3, 4])
array([ 1,  4,  9, 16])
```

Note that I gave a list as input and received an `ndarray` as output. If you absolutely *must* receive the same type of output as you provided as input, you can convert the result before returning it:

```
def square(x):
    in_type = type(x)
    x = np.asarray(x)
    return in_type(x**2)
```

But this incurs an additional cost for little benefit.

Answer (score 0):

Since Python is dynamically typed, and the design philosophy of Python is against the idea of wanting a difference to be obvious when the function is called, this isn't considered *Pythonic*. You can however use the [`isInstance()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance) method to accomplish what you want, if you must that is. For example:

```
def mySquare(x):
    if isinstance(x, int):
        return x**2
    elif isinstance(x, range):
        return [i ** 2 for i in x]

print(mySquare(2)); //4
print(mySquare(range(10))); //[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]
```

[IDEOne link here.](https://ideone.com/jbe6az)

**However, just because you can do something, doesn't mean you should.**

[Refer to this question for further information on isinstance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9225679/how-to-have-different-input-types-for-the-same-function), and I suggest you take a look at [Duck Typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing#In_Python) as well.

Additionally, a [single dispatch function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18876822/python-single-dispatch-functions-pep-443) might also provide what you need, but I am not experienced enough to provide an explanation for this, however, it might be something you want to look into.

Comment: This `isinstance` approach is very fragile - what if the input is a `float`? It would be better to use e.g. `collections.abc.Sequence`, or duck typing (`try` to iterate over the input, and assume it's scalar if that fails).

Comment: @jonrsharpe I agree, I'm trying to make it work for numpy.zeros and I can't get a right result given how isinstance conditionals will not execute if they don't match exactly. definitely unpythonic, but quick and dirty.

Comment: You can provide multiple classes, e.g. `isinstance(x, (int, float))`, but that can end up being more trouble than it's worth.

Answer (score 0):

It would be much better practice and much more maintainable to just do:

```
def foo(n):
    return n ** 2
```

And then build lists, dicts, etc when needed (I'm not super familiar with `numpy` but I imagine there is something similar you could do):

```
foo_list = [foo(n) for n in range(10)]
foo_dict = {n: foo(n) for n in range(10)}
```

And it seems that there is for `numpy` using [numpy.fromiter()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromiter.html). From the docs:

```
iterable = (foo(n) for n in range(5))
foo_arr = np.fromiter(iterable, np.whatever_numpy_datatype)
```

you could even make those into functions if you really needed to:

```
def foo_list(start=0, stop=0):
    return [foo(n) for n in range(start, stop)]

def foo_dict(start=0, stop=0):
    return {n: foo(n) for n in range(10)}
```

Another option as it's easier to ask for forgiveness than permission:

```
def foo(scalar_or_iter):
    try:
        return [n ** 2 for n in scalar_or_iter]
    except TypeError:
        return scalar_or_iter ** 2
```

Comment: To get the square of the elements of a NumPy array `x`, you just write `x**2`.  It would be horribly inefficient to square a NumPy array via a Python-level iteration.

Comment: So it would be more efficient to just make an array like so `foo_arr = np.asarray(some_list)` and then just `foo_arr**2` @MarkDickinson?

Comment: Perhaps.  If you're really starting with a list, you'll need to decide whether it's really worth converting to an array or not.  My point was that if you're *starting* with a NumPy array, it doesn't make sense to iterate over its elements at Python level (and in that case there's no need for the `asarray` call).

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, just write a scalar version of your function and use map for lists etc and imap for iterables (map will not work on those):

```
map(myFunc,myList)
```

and

```
import itertools
itertools.imap(myFunc,myIterable)
```